# Unable to reset setTimeout timer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Here is my pseudocode:

```
if(key.pressed = 'a') {
  activate = true;
}

var mytimeout = function timer_function() {
   // Do stuff;
   setTimeout( function() {
    // do more stuff
   }, 5000);
}

function some_function() {
  
 if(activated) {
   // do stuff
   clearTimeout(mytimeout);

   timer_function();
 }
}

if(mouse.click == true) {
  some_function();
}
```

I want the timer to be reset on each mouse click which calls `some_function()`. What actually happens is that the time is set on first click but never resets after that.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Your second line sets the variable `activate` but you check a variable called `activated` in `some_function()`, are you sure you have this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mytimeout` is a function, not a timeout handle. What you need to store is the result of the `setTimeout` call like this.

```js
var timeoutHandle;
function timer_function() {
   // Do stuff;
   timeoutHandle = setTimeout( function() {
    // do more stuff
   }, 5000);
}

function some_function() {
  
 if(activated) {
   // do stuff
   clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);

   timer_function();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In function `timer_function` return the value of setTimeout

```
var mytimeout = function timer_function() {
   return setTimeout( function() {
       //Do some more stuff
   }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks shivamm that is a nice idea. :) I have accepted the other answer though because it was posted first.

Comment: Please check other answers before posting a duplicate answer

Comment: This just changes the mytimeout-function to return a value, the value still isn't stored anywhere and still wouldn't work with the clearTimeout function without additional changes.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren so the return value won't be stored in `mytimeout`? I guess you are right because it is a function definition and not a function call.

Comment: Exactly, you would still need to call the function stored in `mytimeout` to get the return value.

Answer (score -1):

Thats because in you are only going to replay the Timeout only when the user presses the "a" key. I don't know why you kept it like that but thats probably the reason.!